# JSFiddle - Why is this JQuery Autocomplete not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery-autocomplete, jsfiddle

What is wrong with this piece of code? Why does this JSfiddle not work?

**HTML**

```
<input id="university" name="university" type="text" />
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(function () {

        var jsonsample = [{
            "name": "Stanford University"
        }, {
            "name": "Santa Clara University"
        }]

        $('#university').autocomplete({

            minLength: 2,

            source: 'jsonsample',

            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $('#university').val(ui.item.name);
                return false;
            },

            select: function (event, ui) {

                $('#university').val(ui.item.name);

                return false;
            }
        })


            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)

                .append("<a>" + item.name + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };

    });
```

jsfiddle.net/venomoustoad/9yBcZ

Why do i get 'please use POST request'?

I am ideally looking for autocomplete to populate with the names in the jsonsample object.

Comment: shouldn't it be `.data( "ui-autocomplete" )...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the source as a string, it should not have the quotes

```
source: 'jsonsample',
```

remove them

```
source: jsonsample,
```

You seemed to mistype the demo

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul
```

It should be

```
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul
```

and you need to have a value in your array

```
    [{
        "value": "Stanford University"
        "name": "Stanford University"
    }, {
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NsBGH/